# I need a good tool to style my code - i.e. spacing , brackets, etc

Tags: php, javascript, c++, html, coding-style

I have about 4000 lines of code that I need to re-style.
I'm not doing this by hand.
Are there any tools available that will help change style?

Comment: It would be helpful to state what language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) has a configurable source code formatter that can be triggered automatically on Save and manually with Ctrl+Shift+F (customizable shortcut) for most if not all editor plugins (i.e., most if not all languages). Of those that I use, only PHP Development Tools has configuration limits there.

You really should name the programming/markup language(s) that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try jEdit - they have auto-indentation, and works on most OSes.

http://www.jedit.org/

Answer (score 1):

"Any" IDE will do it for you. So which one are you using ?

Vim : gg , = , G

[Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311912/how-do-i-autoindent-in-netbeans) : "Select the lines you want to reformat (indenting), then hit Alt+Shift+F. Only the selected lines will be reformatted."

Notepad++ : Check out this link posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412427/auto-indent-in-notepad)

Comment: sure notepad++ is another solution .. like i said, "any" ide will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

AStyle (C/C++/Java/C#) command line tool. I use it within any IDE by invoking external command with shortcut.

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/