# Reindent / Format php in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: php, netbeans

How can i reindent php code so that it will look clear in Netbeans 7.4 ??

Example:

I want to convert code (with one click on a button) which looks like this:

```
function helloworld(){echo 'hello world';}
```

To:

```
function helloworld(){
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311912/how-do-i-autoindent-in-netbeans/9818817#9818817

Comment: @Manu This question should be flag as duplicate then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the hotkey:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Or from Menu `Source > Format`

You can even customize formatting from

`Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting`

Answer (score 1):

Right click -> Format

This is a bad question, this could be found easily.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sometimes i can't see the forrest through the trees.