# Automatically formatting a line with semicolon in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Yet another silly question.  I am using netbeans, and need to know how to autoformat a line when I type semicolon.

Example

```
type var=new type();
type var = new type();
```

Comment: Not sure that's possible even with *good* IDEs...

Comment: Visual Studio has this feature, but you have to use C# and I'm trying to learn the underlying features of Java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311912/how-do-i-autoindent-in-netbeans

Comment: I'm aware of the keyboard shortcut, but it would be nice if when complete a line with a semicolon, the line would automatically format.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this do the following

1. Type in the statement without hitting the semicolon
2. Click on the red circle on editor toolbar(Start Macro Recording)
3. Type a semicolon followed by alt shift F followed by a backspace(needed to remove extra semicolon)
4. Click on the icon Stop Macro Recording (next to the Start)

NetBeans will prompt you for a macro name, I called mine `formatline`

Completing a statement with a semicolon will now reformat the the line.