# Copy and Paste from Notepad ++ to NetBeans

Tags: java, text, notepad++, editor

I found similar, but not quite the same question so here is my post:

I write my java code in notepad++, then when I am happy with it, I copy and paste it to NetBeans to test it.  The text copies over quite misaligned sometimes.  Is there a way to fix this or does anyone have another process to suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by misaligned? You can format code indentation in NetBeans. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1311912/10292075

Comment: In the menu bar at the top of NetBeans select **Source** then in the drop down menu select **Format**.

Comment: Do you have the same tab width in both systems? I would suggest using **menu** => **Blank operations** => **Tab to space** in Notepad++ before copying the text.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I will try these solutions.

Comment: Arvind,  There is no checkmarks anywhere on the screen to click.  I read more about it by none of my posted questions give me the option to click a checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(shift + alt + f) works perfectly to format and realign my code in NetBeans!